# jQuery.ajax: first steps. It doesn't go to the url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code below. I expected after submitting the form it goes to "/frontend_dev.php/coche1/new" but it never goes (i added a die("enter") in the corresponding method, but "enter" is not showed) ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.formulario').submit(function () {
        form_data = $.param($(this).serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
            url: "/frontend_dev.php/coche1/new",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            success: function () {
                alert("Data Saved: ");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


<form class="formulario" id="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    <label for="coche1_marca">Marca</label>
    <input type="text" id="coche1_marca" value="FJSDF" name="coche1[marca]">  
    <label for="coche1_modelo">Modelo</label>
    <input type="text" id="coche1_modelo" value="FJSDÑF" name="coche1[modelo]">  
</form>
```

Any help?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Can you check it with Firebug console and see if the AJAX call is out and what is the status of the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a return false at the end of your `.submit()` handler.  Otherwise it fires the AJAX but then immediately submits the form as well, which causes the page to reload since there's no action on the form itself.  Adding return false shows that the AJAX fires as expected.

Comment: Thanks, any way i had to go the Firebug console to see the "enter" string.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything to [prevent the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of submitting the form, so it submits it to the URL specified in the action attribute (although since you failed to include that mandatory attribute, it uses the current URL instead). This happens before the XHR request returns, so the success method never fires.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
...
$('.formulario').submit(function (event)
{
     event.preventDefault(); // This will stop the form from submitting.
     ...
     return false; // Should also stop the form from submitting, but have ran into cases where it does not. Still, include it for good measure.
}
```

Here are some additional things to keep in mind about the event argument:

```
event.preventDefault() // Stops default actions, link redirection, form submission, etc...
event.stopPropagation() // Stops the event from propagating up the DOM tree.
event.stopImmediatePropagation() // Stops the current event and ALL other events on the element from propagating any further up the DOM tree.
```

For more information on event propagation in JQuery, see here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/665/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use post method instead of $.ajax, it work for me !

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32351986)